# How to find the component calling a custom hook in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-custom-hooks

I've a custom hook being called by multiple components, including other custom hooks. I added an useEffect in the custom hook to run on only initial render with `console.trace()`, to figure out the caller component.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.trace()
}, [])
```

But this logs the stack trace with `invokePassiveCreate` at the top. I can't find the caller from the stack trace. Is there another way to figure it out?

[image: stack trace]

Comment: You could try throwing an error in the hook and seeing what the stacktrace is from that

Comment: @MatthewHerbst yeah tried that, it has the same output as `console.trace()`

Answer (score 1):

useEffect is invoked by React so here we did not get the caller of the custom hook or any component. use console.trace() outside useEffect.